# Phase Difference in LTSpice: Op-Amps vs. Voltage Sources

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, ltspice, sine

Below I have two different circuits:

1. The left circuit takes a sine-wave and buffers it on one path and then inverts it on the second path using universal amps. The 180 deg out-of-phase sine waves bias two capacitors (nodes testA and testB). The capacitors are assigned values of C*V (where C is an oscillatory capacitance set up as Cgaps1 and Cgaps2...and V is represented by x, per LTSpice manual).
2. The right circuit is the same exact setup except now I'm using voltage sources directly instead of inverting/buffering with amps.

I am taking the output as the node between the capacitors.

[image]

Based on theory, I expect that the output signal is a high-frequency sine wave (same frequency as the initial 1Meg bias frequency) that is modulated by the Cgaps frequency of 1000 Hz. This modulation is apparent in the envelope of the output. I also expect that the output is in phase with the bias.

Here's my question. If I compare all of the testing points in the picture (testA with testA2...testB with testB2), they all match. However, out1 and out2 are out of phase very slightly and have a different amplitude. All shown below. Why does this occur? I imagine that it has to do with the universal amp, like the phase margin or something like that, but I hate guessing and not understanding why. Note that the op-amp rails at +/- 10 V, not shown. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Reduce the frequency to 1kHz and compare.

Comment: ...and try to find the REASON for all of your observations...

Comment: The two comments above should hint you in the right direction, but I'll add that this is not specific to LTspice (depending on the models, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. They two outputs are in phase for a 1 kHz bias, which initially made me think that the amps weren't responding fast enough (a slew rate issue). I didn't like this train of thought since the outputs of the op-amps are in phase with the outputs of the voltage sources (testA/B with testA2/B2). I increased the slew rate and the out of phase problem remained. Do you have any further hints? I appreciate your time.